# How do I build a query to get the latest row per user where a third criteria is in a separate table?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have three tables

```
CREATE TABLE `LineItems` (
  `LineItemID` int NOT NULL,
  `OrderID` int NOT NULL,
  `ProductID` int NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `LineItems` (`LineItemID`, `OrderID`, `ProductID`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 1),
(3, 2, 3),
(4, 2, 4),
(5, 3, 1),
(6, 4, 2),
(7, 5, 4),
(8, 5, 2),
(9, 5, 3),
(10, 6, 1),
(11, 6, 4),
(12, 7, 4),
(13, 7, 1),
(14, 7, 2),
(15, 8, 1),
(16, 9, 3),
(17, 9, 4),
(18, 10, 3);


CREATE TABLE `Orders` (
  `OrderID` int NOT NULL,
  `UserID` int NOT NULL,
  `OrderDate` datetime NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `Orders` (`OrderID`, `UserID`, `OrderDate`) VALUES
(1, 21, '2021-05-01 00:00:00'),
(2, 21, '2021-05-03 00:00:00'),
(3, 24, '2021-05-06 00:00:00'),
(4, 23, '2021-05-12 00:00:00'),
(5, 21, '2021-05-14 00:00:00'),
(6, 22, '2021-05-16 00:00:00'),
(7, 23, '2021-05-20 00:00:00'),
(8, 21, '2021-05-22 00:00:00'),
(9, 24, '2021-05-23 00:00:00'),
(10, 23, '2021-05-26 00:00:00');

CREATE TABLE `Products` (
  `ProductID` int NOT NULL,
  `ProductTitle` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  `ProductType` enum('doors','windows','flooring') NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO `Products` (`ProductID`, `ProductTitle`, `ProductType`) VALUES
(1, 'French Doors','doors'),
(2, 'Sash Windows','windows'),
(3, 'Sliding Doors','doors'),
(4, 'Parquet Floor','flooring');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f732a26/7):

`Orders` - contains an order date and a user id

`LineItems` - Foreign key to the orders table, contains product ids that are in the order

`Products` - Contains details of the products (including if they are a door, window, or flooring)

I have figured out how to get the latest order per user with

```
SELECT O.* FROM Orders O LEFT JOIN Orders O2 
  ON O2.UserID=O.UserID AND O.OrderDate < O2.OrderDate 
WHERE O2.OrderDate IS NULL;
```

This works fine and is included in the SQL fiddle, along with a query that returns a complete picture for reference.

I am trying to figure out how to get the latest order *with flooring* per user, but I'm not having any luck.

In the SQL fiddle linked above, the intended output for what I am after would be

```
OrderID | UserID | OrderDate
6       | 22     | 2021-05-16T00:00:00Z
5       | 21     | 2021-05-14T00:00:00Z
9       | 24     | 2021-05-23T00:00:00Z
7       | 23     | 2021-05-20T00:00:00Z
```

EDIT: To clarify, in the intended result, two rows (for users 21 and 23) are different than in the query that gets just latest order per user. This is because order IDs 8 and 10 (from the latest order per user query) do not include flooring. The intended query has to find the latest order with flooring from each user to return in the result set.

Comment: Have you tried "order by OrderDate desc;"

Comment: @Jethan - I'm not I understand sure how that would help or where I would put it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the LineItems and Products tables to your query to find orders where flooring was purchased:

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.*
  FROM Orders O
  LEFT JOIN Orders O2 
    ON O2.UserID=O.UserID AND
       O.OrderDate < O2.OrderDate
  INNER JOIN LineItems i
    ON i.OrderID = O.OrderID
  INNER JOIN Products p
    ON p.ProductID = i.ProductID
  WHERE O2.OrderDate IS NULL AND
        p.ProductType = 'flooring'
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=839c779fca3daa954f1dbb4b1ea89461)

Comment: The results from that query do not match the expected results - UserIDs 5 and 7 are not included in the result set.

Comment: Well, that's the general idea. You can refine it from there.

Comment: Also, your original query does not return any data for UserIDs 5 and 7.

Comment: Wow I totally typed the value from the wrong field and only just noticed. I meant UserIDs 21 and 23 (OrderIDs 5 and 7) are not in the result set from your query, but should be as per the expected results.

Comment: Your original query returns UserID 21 matched with OrderID 8, and UserId23 matched with OrderID 10. I think your original query has problems.

Comment: In the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f732a26/7) that I linked, the original query (which only gets the latest order per user) correctly returns 4 rows. As per my post, the expected result for latest order *with flooring* per user would also contain 4 rows, of which two rows (for users 21 and 23) would be earlier orders than the ones in the original query (IDs 8 and 10), as those orders did not include flooring. Your proposed query only returns 2 rows, the rows for user IDs 21 and 23 are missing. Also thanks for the help, sorry if I poorly communicated what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: To clarify - I am not looking only for orders which had flooring, I am looking for the most recent order with flooring per user. If a user had never ordered flooring, then they shouldn't be in the result set, but anyone who has ordered it at least once should have a row with the order ID and date of the last time they ordered flooring.